# Is there a list of APIs not accesible from an iOS extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-extensions

I read on ([this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6)) Apple documentation that there are some APIs not available for an extension. But it doesn't specify which ones and I was not able to find any specification.

Is there any additional documentation around this?

Comment: There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/joeymeyer/0cb033698bfa5a0420f6) with the APIs marked as `NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE`. I'm not sure that it is exhaustive though...

Comment: Hey, that works as a first answer haha thanks!